# I have error when try to extract acf field in wordpress javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, userid

It will be ok when I write this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var user_id = '<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>'; // Test ok
    var subject = "<?php echo the_field('subject', 'user_1'); ?>"; // For test
    $("#subject").val(subject); // Extract successfully
    
});
</script>
```

But it has blank error when I use dynamic variable "user_id", like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var user_id = '<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>'; // Test ok
    var subject = "<?php echo the_field('subject', 'user_" + user_id + "'); ?>"; // Blank error
    $("#subject").val(subject);
    
});
</script>
```

Do you know where is my wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even use this method it's not optimal.
Please do not use JavaScript within a PHP file. To make it more officiant please use "wp_localize_script"

So something like this:

```
wp_localize_script( 'the-js-handler-you-want-to-have-this-object', 'siteData', [
    'subject' => the_field( 'subject', 'user_' . get_current_user_id() ),
] );
```

And then in the Js file, you can just use it like this:

```
console.log( siteData.subject )
```

Just to note code fix for your case is ""

```
var user_id = '<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>';
var subject = "<?php echo the_field( 'subject', 'user_' + user_id ); ?>";
```

Comment: var subject = "<?php echo the_field( 'subject', 'user_' + user_id ); ?>";
This can't get parameter "user_id" in javascript, it's just a text in blockquote ""

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I 'm successful

I use php syntax in blockquote, instead of javascript syntax
Because javascript syntax will be misunderstood in php code

```
var subject = "<?php echo the_field('subject', 'user_' .get_current_user_id() ); ?>";
```